# Как настроить environment для библиотеки?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6, environment-variables

У меня есть решение, в котором 4 проекта. Один из них - asp .net. Внутри него есть launchsettings, где указывается aspnetcore_environment: debug.
И есть 3 библиотеки классов.
Так вот в одном из классов мне нужно получать строку подключения до базы данных, и когда я создаю миграцию через ef core, он не видит строку подключения, т.к у меня есть только appsettings.Debug, где указана эта строка. Но если я укажу строку подключения в файле appsettings.Development - без проблем создаётся миграция.
А если я запускаю всё - строка подключения из appsettings.Debug ищется без проблем
Как поменять Development на Debug для всех библиотек в решении? У меня Visual Studio 2022.

Понимаю, что дефолтовый environment там Development, судя по всему) Но как изменить? launchsettings туда добавить - не спасло

**UPD:**
Помогла команда `Add-Migration test -Args '--environment Debug'` при создании миграции, но можно ли это в какие-то проперти засунуть, чтобы каждый раз environment не писать?